# Computing the analytic solution to the non-homogeneous 3D wave equation

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, computational-physics

I'm working on solving the non-homogeneous equation numerically.

$$ \frac{\partial ^2 w}{\partial t^2} = a^2 \nabla^2w + \Phi(x, y, z, t)$$

with initial conditions

$$ w= f(x, y, z) \space \text{at} \space t=0 $$
$$ \partial_t w= g(x, y, z) \space \text{at} \space t=0 $$

In order to check if the algorithm is implemented succesfully, I need an analytical solution to the problem. The book I am consulting has the analytic solution (to a Cauchy problem) to the equation written as follows:

$$w(x, y,z,t)= \iint\limits_{r=at} \frac{f(ξ, η, ζ)}{r}dS + \frac{1}{4 \pi a} \iint\limits_{r=at}\frac{g(ξ, η, ζ)}{r}dS +\\ \frac{1}{4 \pi a^2} \iiint\limits_{r \leq at}\frac{1}{r} \Phi\left(ξ, η, ζ, \tau - \frac{r}{a}\right)~ dξ dηdζ, $$

where $r = \sqrt[]{(ξ-x)^2 + (η-y)^2 + (ζ-z)^2}$ and the integration is performed over the surface of the 2-sphere ($r = at$) and the volume of the 2-sphere (ball) ($r ≤ at$) with center at $(x ,y , z)$.

The problem is that I am not sure:

1. what $ξ, η$, and $ζ$ are. Furthermore
2. how I can write them down in a computer-friendly way.
3. why there is a formulation of the $L_2$ norm between these letters

Do you know how one can write this solution in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be using Green functions. Answering your particular questions:

1. These are spatial variables used for the integration. You are basically using superposition of point loads (convolution with Green functions) and these are the coordinates of each point load. Notice that these are dummy variables because they disappear after integration.
2. I think that they are already in a "computer friendly way". You could rewrite them as the sum of disjoint integrals where you have a sum over patches (or elements) that correspond to a discretization of space.
3. I guess that you are referring to $r$. This is the distance between the location of the point source and your evaluation point.

I would suggest that you try the method of manufactured solutions to do the verification for your algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! A follow up question: what is my point source? How do I find that? That feels unclear to me mathematically.

Comment: @vlamas, you don't have a point source. But you have a distributed source $\Phi$ that can be written a as the superposition of infinitely many point sources, that's were the integrals with the $1/r$ appear.